# Zabbix:SNMP не активируется

Tags: zabbix, snmp

Все настройки вроде сделал правильно.Значок не отображается зеленым.Что может быть?

Когда делаю snmp тест,в latest data ничего не отображается.Кто знает причину и как это исправить ?

Comment: Занесите лучше ваш комментарий в сам вопрос, нажав кнопку "править" ниже вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

нужно проверить какой пароль стоит на стороне сервера, и сверить с тем что у тебя в zabbix вписан